# Don't get password prompt when ssh-ing from fedora

Tags: macos, password, ssh

I can ssh successfully with password from one mac running Yosemite to another, but when I try to use password authentication for ssh from fedora to either Yosemite system, I never get a password prompt - even if I disable key exchange and explicitly require password authentication. All are on the same local network.

Looking at the differences between ssh -vvv from Fedora and Yosemite, the difference seems to be that Fedora has disabled md5 authentication by default (see [Redhat bugzilla 1373835](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1373835), whereas Yosemite the successful login from Yosemite uses it. However nothing changes if I add

```
-o MACs=hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
```

to the Fedora command line. Upgrading from Yosemite is infeasible (hardware limitations). Do you have any suggestions?

PS could someone with enough points please add Fedora/Redhat, or even linux, tags to this to make it more discoverable (unix, which is the narrowest I can add, is far too broad to be useful)?

When I enter

```
ssh -vvv -o PreferredAuthentications=keyboard-interactive -o PubkeyAuthentication=no user@host
```

this is the end of the output I get from Fedora (everything before corresponds fairly accurately between Fedora  and Yosemite logins, modulo slightly differing available encryptions and diagnostic formats):

```
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes256-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes256-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 need=32 dh_need=32
debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 need=32 dh_need=32
debug3: send packet: type 34
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<8192<8192) sent
Connection closed by 192.168.2.12 port 22
```

Whereas this is what I see in the corresponding Yosemite output:

```
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 132/256
debug2: bits set: 512/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 28:0d:78:e3:61:3a:72:5e:e5:17:b9:27:0b:ad:33:5f
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "192.168.2.12" from file "/Users/rim/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /Users/rim/.ssh/known_hosts:7
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host '192.168.2.12' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/rim/.ssh/known_hosts:7
debug2: bits set: 519/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /Users/rim/.ssh/id_rsa (0x0),
debug2: key: /Users/rim/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred keyboard-interactive
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: 
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug2: input_userauth_info_req
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
Password:
```

Comment: there may be something strange going on with the interfaces I would do a tcpdump and see if that brings up something interesting.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that this is due to a bug in the implementation of openssh in OSX Yosemite (too small message buffers to accommodate the modern range of available cyphers - please see [Redhat Bugzilla bug 1373835](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1026430) for details). The workaround given there, to limit the cypher list by specifying it explicitly, as for instance

```
ssh -o HostKeyAlgorithms=ssh-rsa,ssh-dss -o KexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 -o Ciphers=aes128-cbc,3des-cbc -o MACs=hmac-md5,hmac-sha1 user@host
```

works for me.